# How to avoid using global functions in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js

I have a global function in my main JS file and i need to call it several times from a module. I heard it is bad because it can create a function name collision between a local (from module) and a global function name (from main js). The global function can be called 100 times from the require module. Is there an alternative way to achieve the following without using global functions?

main.js with global function

```
const myMod = require('./module.js");
global.myGlobalFunction = function(param){
console.log("do something with",param);
}
```

module.js with the calls of the global function:

```
module.exports = function(){
myGlobalFunction("class");
myGlobalFunction("this");
myGlobalFunction("bubu");
// other jobs to do
}
```

Comment: What is the actual question here?

Comment: You should learn about Node modules: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Answer (score 0):

The neater way to do it is to use modules like this:

## module.js

```
class myGlobalUtil {
  myGlobalFunction(param){
    console.log("do something with",param)
  }
  get GetFromParam(myParam){
    return this.myGlobalFunction(myParam);
  }
}
module.exports = myGlobalUtil;
```